# Setting spannable string in android with combination of non-spannable strings

Tags: android, string, spannablestring

I have several strings uploaded to a String[]. These strings are set on a textview. However, I set the previous strings on my textview, as well. I need some of the strings to be red colored. I've heard of the SpannableString class which does exactly what I want, but the following call defeats my purpose of setting all the previous strings.

```
if(string from String[] contains ("R2")){//pseudo code
//build spanstring with all its properties
//combinedstrings = combinedstrings + spanstring;
}
else{
//string = string from String[]
//combinedstrings = combinedstrings + string;
}

textview.setText(spanstring, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

As you can see, this call only allows to set the spanstring not the combination of the spanstring including the non-spannable strings. I need the combination of both to be set at the same time. 
I need a call that would set the text on the textview of both types of strings
the non-spannable and spannable ones.

thanks for any suggestions

Comment: `"As you can see"`, actually no, what combination do you mean? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: String[] a = new Strin[3] , a[0] = "non-spannable", a[1]="spannable", a[2] = "spannable" , combinedstring = a[0] + a[1] + a[2]; , how can I set combinedstring in my textview so that it includes the spannable and non-spannable properties? @pskink

Comment: `TextUtils#concat` and also `SpannableStringBuilder` methods `append` / `insert` / `replace`

Comment: thanks for the tips @pskink

Answer (score 0):

Build the CharSequence you pass to setText with a SpannableStringBuilder.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html  This class allows you to append either string or spans and can be built into a single CharSequence.